# Finding the smallest number's index

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multiprocessing

I have the following (sampled) dictionary `A` that originally has over 17,000 keys, and each array's length is just over 600,000 (same for all). I am trying to find the key of the smallest number across arrays for each of 600,000 inputs. For instance, in the below dictionary, I want to get i = 3093094 for j = 0 because 45.16672136 is the smallest across the first indices of all arrays. Similarly, i = 1157086 for j = 1 because 1.53174068 is the smallest.

```
A = {3093094: array([45.16672136,  1.68053313, 13.78822307, ..., 36.18798239,
        36.09565274, 35.85261821]),
 1156659: array([45.46286695,  1.69632425, 13.81351489, ..., 36.54544469,
        36.45329774, 36.20969689]),
 1156667: array([45.43970605,  1.69026244, 13.81365067, ..., 36.51934187,
        36.42716964, 36.18364528]),
 1156792: array([45.29956347,  1.57736575, 13.90834355, ..., 36.43079348,
        36.33804273, 36.09623309]),
 1157086: array([45.38149498,  1.53174068, 13.98398836, ..., 36.57985343,
        36.48684657, 36.2457831 ]),
 1430072: array([45.46114909,  1.58096885, 13.95459557, ..., 36.64775128,
        36.55496457, 36.31324461]),
 1668445: array([45.44073352,  1.5941793 , 13.92953699, ..., 36.60630965,
        36.51361336, 36.27162926]),
 3055958: array([45.45006118,  1.57686417, 13.95499241, ..., 36.63558996,
        36.54278917, 36.30111176]),
 1078241: array([45.56175847,  1.77256163, 13.75586274, ..., 36.61441986,
        36.52264105, 36.27795081])}
```

I have the below multiprocessing solution method but looking for a more efficient way as it takes too long to process.

```
import numpy as np
import os
from multiprocessing import Pool


C = range(len(A[3093094]))

def closest(All_inputs):
    (A,j) = All_inputs
    B = list(A.keys())
    my_list = [A[i][j] for i in B]
    return(B[np.argmin(np.array(my_list))])

with Pool(processes=os.cpu_count()) as pool:
    results = pool.map(closest, [(A,j) for j in C])
```

A challenge is to duplicate A in multiprocessing as it is huge in size. Do you have any Pythonic approaches to quickly complete this supposedly trivial computation?

Comment: Maybe you can slice your dictionary to chunks?  After that you can use this chunks in threads

Comment: Slicing the dictionary is the most time-consuming part in my experience. I think, `my_list = [A[i][j] for i in B]` is doing that slicing. If I do the slicing before the multiprocessing, then I do the majority of the computation in serial. Otherwise, I duplicate a huge dictionary...

Comment: The second idea: can you sort your input? that you have a[key][0] - be always the minimum of array

Comment: Then, I lose the order in each array and do not know if I compare A[key][0] to A[another_key][0]. I also don't see how it could help. I am not trying to find the index of the array with the minimum value for each key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your memory is big enough. May be you can try this, using pandas. If still slow, try using dask. Both example were list below.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import dask.dataframe as dd
from tqdm import tqdm
test_data = {}
for i in tqdm(range(2000)):
    test_data[i] = np.random.randint(0, 10000, 600000)

# test one
# print(test_data)
now = time.time()
df = pd.DataFrame(test_data)
min_idx = df.idxmin(axis=1)
result_one = dict(zip(range(2000), min_idx.tolist()))
# print(result_one)
print(time.time() - now)

# test two
now = time.time()
df = pd.DataFrame(test_data)
ddf = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=multiprocessing.cpu_count())
min_idx = ddf.idxmin(axis=1).compute(scheduler="processes")
result_two = dict(zip(range(2000), min_idx.tolist()))
# print(result_two)
print(time.time() - now)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I am not trying to find the index of the array with the minimum value for each key.

Comment: `df.idxmin(axis=1);` `result_one = dict(zip(range(2000), min_idx.tolist()))` does what is needed in around 40 mins.

Comment: Sorry, I rested for a few days. I changed the answer according to your comments.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried the following on a machine with 12 cores and 16G RAM:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool, cpu_count
from time import perf_counter

def closest(values):
    return np.argmin(np.array(values))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Build A inside __main__ (otherwise each process builds it again)
    num_keys = 10_000
    arr_len = 100_000
    rng = np.random.default_rng()
    A = {
        key: rng.integers(0, 1000, arr_len)
        for key in range(1000, 1000 + num_keys)
    }

    # Multiprocessing
    start = perf_counter()
    with Pool(processes=cpu_count()) as p:
        indices = p.imap(closest, zip(*A.values()), chunksize=1000)
        keys = tuple(A.keys())
        results = [keys[i] for i in indices]
    end = perf_counter()
    print(f"Duration (np.argmin mp): {end - start:.2f}")

    # np.argmin directly
    start = perf_counter()
    arr = np.array([*A.values()])
    keys = tuple(A.keys())
    results = [keys[i] for i in np.argmin(arr, axis=0)]
    end = perf_counter()
    print(f"Duration (np.argmin direct): {end - start:.2f}")
```

Duration results:

```
Duration (np.argmin mp): 1258.07
Duration (np.argmin direct): 563.84
```

---

Results for a small sample (`num_keys = 4`, `arr_len = 8`):

```
A =
{1000: [879, 130, 114, 973, 691, 394, 122, 215],
 1001: [221, 482, 510, 319, 454, 585, 767, 138],
 1002: [982, 526, 971, 168, 185, 477, 838, 37],
 1003: [675, 293, 769, 878, 611, 695, 237, 129]}
results = [1001, 1000, 1000, 1002, 1002, 1000, 1000, 1002]
results = [1001, 1000, 1000, 1002, 1002, 1000, 1000, 1002]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will implement and see the duration in my case. I have a question though. I use Jupyter Notebook, and it handles multiprocessing a bit weirdly that always confuses me. Just to make it work, I leave my functions into a separate py file which requires me to move over all necessary local variables (defined on ipynb) to this py for multiprocessing. Basically, I call the function from py file and run using multiprocessing in ipynb. Do you know if the above method (pushing parallel use intended functions to top and wrapping the rest with `__main__`) works for ipynb?

Comment: Sorry for irrelevant questions, but why is chunksize = 1000?

Comment: @tcokyasar Regarding your first comment: Unfortunately, I barely know anything about Jupyter Notebooks. Regarding the `chunksize`: There's no clear rule what the best size is. I usually play around a bit to tune it. So, I'm not saying the 1000 is optimal (I should have made that clear). Anyway, I'd recommend to try if the 2. version, without multiprocessing, works, because in all the scenarios I've looked at it seemed to be faster.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work and ought to be faster than converting each column to a Python list with an unpythonic list comprehension and then back to a NumPy array:

```
K = np.array(list(A))
V = np.array(list(A.values()))
print(K[V.argmin(axis=0)])
```

Output for your example data (with the `...` removed):

```
[3093094 1157086 1078241 3093094 3093094 3093094]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZZO7bttAEEV7fgVLCRCIeT8CuHDt3o3hQkWQCIhlQZKDGEG@XRlzV4mYECzI5e6cufcOD@/nr697vlx2L4fX43ncv70c3sftadwfhmF7PG7fx7t6nubHYbivt58MWbd8GufF1ZPohGZOyLYZR5wsQJmRNyPy5BFEDL4Z2SYMzyDOzTD2qxYh1ZRcaodOoWQYhM/r2oOoZpq3IDEKs9QGSmMS0hkUyIoSOYNUVERsCRJlSp9BNhFkHY/8CzJfgDgdDK4gICORK8gUrClSTJaStQSRYxWXrplNlOIPyJNuQZSln8VnkLpXcW@KEoKFVecyUh4WKhYg5oCC8ab5aMQVzBXkEHYL4kBJyWggRhewaKDgjPhI70NRRaTFXSoKC6nGmnWiHoxjA1Vj4LTMCIsE2UBRfUV0RZVLai9j4q5IS0WqUsb1HTVDZbr1YbBqQXQBEnBmpQZKwXJobCBKZcs2DAZWtpguQZUictf8kRcl2Qxi0GoyFiAFKFHdOrewYl0VZZJgA1VYkWlLUAUUiV0RYF3eQAgedfQWpIau0YfBnerd@n9UpY368BqKYMY/IKJqC7Qr8lSIsu7XMDzc/MOrb7vTeXW/Xg@P/69O37ff3j6fVuv6fDju9ufVw9Nj7fjystuvtj92pztYP68vl98)

Comment: `V = np.array(list(A.values()))` takes around 5 minutes. But, `K[V.argmin(axis=0)]` takes forever.

Comment: @tcokyasar How long does `V = np.array([v[0:1000] for v in A.values()])` take and how long does `K[V.argmin(axis=0)]` take after that?